# DeepFace.analyze: AttributeError: module 'keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'populate_dict_with_module_objects

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

I am using DeepFace to analyze/classify some face images

The process is simple, I download an image into a folder and then I analyze it using DeepFace.analyze

```
from deepface import DeepFace


url = "url_to_imagefile.jpg"  

# Download image
file_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "other_files_ignore_this/image.jpg")
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, r'{}'.format(save_path))
print(os.path.isfile(file_path))

# Analyze image
obj = DeepFace.analyze(img_path=file_path, actions=['age', 'gender', 'race', 'emotion'])
```

This process gives me an AttributeError

`*** AttributeError: module 'keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'populate_dict_with_module_objects'`

This are my tensorflow packages installed:

```
tensorboard==2.5.0
tensorboard-data-server==0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.0
tensorflow==2.5.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Its default facial detector backend is mtcnn. That trouble comes from that dependency as mentioned [here](https://github.com/serengil/deepface/issues/254#issuecomment-859195194).

```
obj = DeepFace.analyze(img_path = file_path
, actions=['age', 'gender', 'race', 'emotion']
, detector_backend = 'opencv')
```

You can use opencv, ssd or retinaface without any trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and this solution (posted by kirthan0899 here: https://github.com/fizyr/keras-retinanet/issues/1538) worked for me:

```
!pip uninstall keras -y  
!pip uninstall keras-nightly -y  
!pip uninstall keras-Preprocessing -y  
!pip uninstall keras-vis -y  
!pip uninstall tensorflow -y  

!pip install tensorflow==2.3.0  
!pip install keras==2.4
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should make sure your image files are not corrupted or something else because I successfully run deep face with the latest [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow) 2.5 on colab. Though the [requirement](https://github.com/serengil/deepface/blob/master/requirements.txt) version for this package to run is 1.9 and there was also a similar [discussion](https://github.com/serengil/deepface/issues/246) you may wish to go through.

I tested on colab with the following version (by default, no change).

```
pip freeze | grep tensorflow

tensorflow==2.5.0
tensorflow-datasets==4.0.1
tensorflow-estimator==2.5.0
tensorflow-gcs-config==2.5.0
tensorflow-hub==0.12.0
tensorflow-metadata==1.0.0
tensorflow-probability==0.12.1
```

**Run DeepFace**

```
!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace

obj = DeepFace.analyze(img_path="/content/a.png",
                       actions=['age', 'gender', 'race', 'emotion'])
obj
```

```
{'age': 30,
 'dominant_emotion': 'happy',
 'dominant_race': 'middle eastern',
 'emotion': {'angry': 1.4167338413528796e-06,
  'disgust': 1.0070460736690082e-16,
  'fear': 1.4578033333441376e-12,
  'happy': 100.0,
  'neutral': 2.3746911104183255e-07,
  'sad': 1.3744319267774974e-10,
  'surprise': 4.669798076874232e-11},
 'gender': 'Man',
 'race': {'asian': 0.0026936733561638694,
  'black': 0.0007858925087059574,
  'indian': 0.3253198189851534,
  'latino hispanic': 4.1496003657341225,
  'middle eastern': 57.77809964287875,
  'white': 37.74350510498912},
 'region': {'h': 450, 'w': 345, 'x': 88, 'y': 140}}
```

Here is the version of [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow) and [keras](/questions/tagged/keras).

```
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow import keras 
tf.__version__, keras.__version__
('2.5.0', '2.5.0')
```